# How to print multiple html tags in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to print the multiple input boxes using jquery
I am using the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#taxId").change(function(){
        var tax_id=$("#taxId").val();

            $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/pranasInventory/get_tax_detail",
                    data:{tax_id:tax_id},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        var json_obj = $.parseJSON(data);//parse JSON
                        var len=json_obj.length;
                        for (var i=0;i<len;i++) 
                        {
                            var output=json_obj[i].tax_detail+"<input id='taxcal' name='taxcal' placeholder='0.00'>";
                            $('#taxDetail').html(output);
                            console.log(output);
                        }

                    }
                });
        });
        });
</script>
```

It print only one input tag.
my console message like this

```
Service tax @ 14%<input id='taxcal' name='taxcal' placeholder='0.00'>
swachh bharat cess @ 0.5%<input id='taxcal' name='taxcal'placeholder='0.00'>
```

I want print two input box.
please help me

Comment: Are you going to add several inputs with same id ? That's invalid

Answer (score 1):

The [`html` function](http://api.jquery.com/html/) replaces the whole content.

You might replace

```
var len=json_obj.length;
for (var i=0;i<len;i++) {
    var output=json_obj[i].tax_detail+"<input id='taxcal' name='taxcal' placeholder='0.00'>";
    $('#taxDetail').html(output);
    console.log(output);
}
```

with

```
$('#taxDetail').append(json_obj.map(function(obj){
    return $("<input placeholder='0.00'>");
});
```

but you need to decide how to handle the ids of the added inputs as you can't obviously use the same for all.

Answer (score 0):

.html replaces the whole content of the div. You must use JQuery append or prepend methods.